# Colouring the area under curve of plotted list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to generate graphs where there are several curves at once:

```
for i in data.find():
    a=[]
    for element in i["counts"]:
        a.append(element["total"])
    plt.plot(a)

plt.show()
```

I would like to be able to color specific areas under each curve. Say, for curve 1, the interval x:[3,21], x:[28, 29] and x:[42, 51]

I believe that I **cannot** use a variation of the following because y is not a function of x. y is just a list of integers.

```
plt.fill_between(x,y,0,color='0.8')
```

Is there a way to get around this problem? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot(a)` is [equivalent to](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) `plt.plot(np.arange(len(a)),a)`, with that, it becomes easier to see how you could use [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between):

```
where = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=bool)
where[3:21] = True
plt.fill_between(np.arange(len(a)),a,where=where)
```

As a side note,

```
a=[]
for element in i["counts"]:
    a.append(element["total"])
```

Is generally nicer written as a list comprehension:

```
a = [element['total'] for element in i['counts']]
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I be able to fill the curve for several intervals, i.e. where[3:21], and where[34:38]?